# Is it legal to create QCoreApplication object not in main()'s thread?

Tags: c++, qt

Following this code:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // qDebug() << "Whatever"; <- uncommenting this makes the constructor to print a warning
  std::thread thread([&]()
     {
        QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
        qDebug() << "main thread is " << app.thread();
     });
  thread.join();
  qDebug() << "current thread is " << QThread::currentThread();

  return 0;
}
```

It compiles and doesn't crash, no warnings during runtime. QCoreApplication is created not in main()'s thread.

However, if the qDebug() function call is uncommented before creating QCoreApplication object, there is printed a warning:

```
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
```

Is it legal to create QCoreApplication not in main()'s thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#details), it is legal, but not recommended:

> In general, we recommend that you create a QCoreApplication, QGuiApplication or a QApplication object in your main() function as early as possible

Comment: Reading it slightly differently, I would argue that it is implied the instance is created in the main thread.

Comment: @JonHarper Creating an instance of `*Application` is in charge to the user, so the documentation cannot do anything else, but to recommend something. As the OP said, he succeeded in creating it even in another thread, so I guess the one in the answer is a meaningful interpretation. Anyway, good point of view.

Comment: @skypjack, I've heard that you can't get the event loop working on Mac OS in non-main thread.